# Demo for playing around with HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, canvas

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I want to improve my skills. I decided to write a simple application that adds a GUI to `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. I have just barely started and there are not many functionalities yet. I wonder however whether this is a proper way to write OOP in JavaScript? Will it be easy to maintain once it grows bigger? Are there any beginner mistakes in my code that I cannot see right now.

I use some nested loops here. How does it affect performace? What if I have dozens of such loops and if there are multiple levels of nesting?

You can find the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/przemoo83/canvas-api-explorer/tree/95a447a2cead1ff8ea22a5c53e53ebe7c6ec45ee) and a demo as well.  Any feedback is much appreciated.

```
/*
Canvas Api Explorer
Author: przemoo83
*/

(function(){
    var canvas,methods, properties, select;

    //canvas constructor
    var Canvas = function (id) { 
        this.container = document.getElementById(id); 
        this.ctx = this.container.getContext("2d"); 
        this.resize = function (w, h) { 
            this.container.width = w; 
            this.container.height = h; 
        }
        this.findProperties();
        this.findMethods();

    }; 

    //find properties
    Canvas.prototype.findProperties = function(){
        properties = [];
        for (var key in this.ctx){
            if(typeof(this.ctx[key]) !== 'function'){             
                properties.push({
                    prop: key,
                    val: this.ctx[key]
                });             
            }
        }
    }
    //find methods
    Canvas.prototype.findMethods = function(){
        methods = [];
        for (var key in this.ctx){
            if(typeof(this.ctx[key]) == 'function'){         

                for (var customValue in Methods){ //custom Methods object
                    if(customValue == key){
                        methods.push({
                            prop: key,
                            val: Methods[customValue]
                        });

                    }
                }  

            }
        }
    }

    // populate properties <select> fields
    var populateProperties = function(){
       var propertiesNames = document.querySelector('#properties');
       var propertiesValues = document.querySelector('#properties-values');
       for(var key in properties){
           var option = document.createElement('option');
           option.setAttribute('value', properties[key].prop);
           option.innerHTML = properties[key].prop;
           propertiesNames.appendChild(option);

           var input = document.createElement('input');
           setAttributes(input,{
               'value': properties[key].val,
               'id': properties[key].prop,
               'class': 'canvas-value'
           });
           propertiesValues.appendChild(input);
       }

    }

    // populate methods <select> fields
    var populateMethods = function(){
       var methodsList = document.querySelector('#methods');
       var methodsValues = document.querySelector('#methods-values');
       var customMethodAttributes;
       for(var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++){
           var option = document.createElement('option');
           option.setAttribute('value', methods[i].prop);
           option.innerHTML = methods[i].prop;
           methodsList.appendChild(option);
           var method = document.createElement('div');
           setAttributes(method,{
               'id': methods[i].prop,
               'class': 'canvas-value'
               });
           method.innerHTML = '<h5>' + methods[i].prop + '</h5>';
           methodsValues.appendChild(method);
           console.log(methods[i].prop);
           customMethodAttributes = methods[i].val;
                for (var key in customMethodAttributes){
                    var label = document.createElement('label');
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    var br = document.createElement('br');
                    setAttributes(label,{
                        'for': key,
                    });
                    label.innerHTML = key;
                    setAttributes(input,{
                        'id': key,
                        'value':  customMethodAttributes[key]
                    });
                    method.appendChild(label);
                    method.appendChild(input);
                    method.appendChild(br);

                }
        }
     }

    //display proper value of each property and method
    var showValue = function(){
        var currentValue = document.querySelectorAll('.canvas-value');
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValue.length; i++){
             currentValue[i].style.display = 'none';
             if(this.value === currentValue[i].id) {           
                 currentValue[i].style.display = 'block';
             }
        }       
    }
    //detect browser script (taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286594/javascript-detecting-browser-version)
    var browserDetect = function(){
        function findMe(){
            var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
            M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
            if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
                tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
                return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
            }
            if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
                tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
                if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
            }
            M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
            if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
            return M.join(' ');
        }
        var browserName = findMe();
        var browserInfo = document.querySelector('#browser-name');
        browserInfo.innerHTML = browserName;
    }

    // prevent reloading page on submit
    var preventReloading = function(){
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        var validateMe = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        };
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++){
            forms[i].addEventListener('submit', validateMe);
        }
    }
    //find mouse coordinates
    var findMouse = function() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        var locateMouse = function(e) {

            var mouseX, mouseY;

            if(e.offsetX) {
                mouseX = e.offsetX;
                mouseY = e.offsetY;
            }
            else if(e.layerX) {
                mouseX = e.layerX;
                mouseY = e.layerY;

                }
            document.querySelector('#mouseX').innerHTML = mouseX;
            document.querySelector('#mouseY').innerHTML = mouseY;
        }
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', locateMouse);


    }

    //fix for Firefox not reseting default <select> option after refresh
    var resetSelect = function(){
        var options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
        for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
            options[i].selected = options[i].defaultSelected;
        }

    }
    //helper functions
    var setAttributes = function(el, attrs) {
        for(var key in attrs) {
            el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
        }
    }

    // initialize function
    var init = function(){
        canvas = new Canvas("canvas");
        preventReloading();
        browserDetect();
        resetSelect();
        var canvasSize = document.querySelector('#cs');    
        var resizeCanvas = function(){
            var width = document.querySelector('#width');
            var height = document.querySelector('#height');
            if(width.value > 800 || height.value > 600) {
                width.value = 800;
                height.value = 600;
                alert('Maximum size is 800x600');
            }
            canvas.resize(width.value, height.value)
        }
        canvasSize.addEventListener('click', resizeCanvas);      
        findMouse();
        populateProperties();
        populateMethods();

        //attach listeners
        select = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
        for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
            select[i].addEventListener('change', showValue );
        }
    }
    return { 
        // onload event
        load : function () { 
            window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
                init(); 
            }, false); 
        } 
    } 
})().load();
```

Comment: right off the back, dont use querySelectorAll, its not cross browser. iOS 8.* contains a bug where selecting siblings of filtered id selections are no longer working (for example #a + p). IE8 partial support.

Comment: your browser dection is actually from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript

Comment: @theamazing according to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) `querySelectorAll` is supported for nearly 95% of users. The iOS 8.* bug is actually represented by the much more obscure `anything#id ~/+ not-an-id` -[source cited by can I use for the bug](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/290). I suppose that's why Apple didn't fix the bug despite knowing about it well before even 8.1.0 came out. Also, `#a p` is actually given as an example of a selector that **works** in the bug report source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not working because `Methods` is not defined. If there is a definition of it, please add it. `ReferenceError: Methods is not defined`